# Firestore rules - update blocks create?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have the following rule set on my firestore:

```
match /names/{nameId} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow update: if request.auth.token.creator == true && request.writeFields.size() == 1 && ('images' in request.writeFields);
  allow create: if request.auth.token.creator == true;
}
```

However, when I'm trying to create a new object using java(kotlin) client:

```
val data = hashMapOf(
  "name" to name
)

mFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_USERS).add(data)
        .addOnSuccessListener { doc ->
            Log.i(TAG, "On New Document: " + doc.id)
        }.addOnFailureListener { ex ->
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed adding document: ", ex)
        }
```

If I change the rules to make update same as create:

```
match /names/{nameId} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow update: if request.auth.token.creator == true;
  allow create: if request.auth.token.creator == true;
}
```

The java code will now work.

What am I missing here? why is update blocking creates?

p.s.
Just to make sure, I'm removing all documents from my collection in firestore before running the code. Either way though, "add" method generates a random id, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: How are you testing your rules?  In the console simulator?